# Placing plot in tkinter window also shows up as a pop up

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to place a 2x2 plot in a tkinter window, however when I try to plot it also delivers a pop-up with the same data.

My plots are scattered into several methods of a class but here is the overall structure:

```
class Testing(ctk.CTkFrame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        """Initialise the testing window"""
        ctk.CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        plt.ion()
        plt.show()
    def run(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(221)
        self.ax2 = self.fig.add_subplot(222)
        self.ax3 = self.fig.add_subplot(223)
        self.ax4 = self.fig.add_subplot(224)
        canvas  = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self)
        canvas._tkcanvas.grid(row=1, rowspan=3, columnspan = 3, column = 5)
        self.live_plot()
```

Live plot is a routine which is called using `.after` to repeatedly read data and plot it in real time. How do I resolve the issue of two sets of graphs appearing. One in the Frame and another as a pop up?

Comment: What happens when you remove `plt.show()`? My guess is that it is drawing the plot with your Tkinter code but the `plt.show()` is making it also come as a pop-up

Comment: It didn't work - maybe it's to do with the fact its a real time plot. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @MichaelS. Ah so the ```plt.ion``` was causing the error which is weird as I needed it for the live plot to work originally...

Comment: I knew, at least with PySimpleGUI using TKinter widgets, that you didn't need to call `plt.show()` after you drew it to the canvas (because it was drawn to the canvas obviously) so I was hoping it was something simple like that too. Easy fixes are the best!